# Algorithm to tell if an infinite sequence is random or not?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, algorithms, computer-science, dynamical-systems

### Background

I recently came up with an algorithm which creates patterns.

Consider the famous sequence of the primes. They have considerable amount of "structure" but no "obvious pattern". I will illustrate "row math" making a pattern emerge with the example of primes:

### Row math

\begin{equation}
2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,\dots
\end{equation}

Now we will take the modulus/absolute difference of every element with its adjacent neighbor.
\begin{equation}
2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,\dots
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
1,2,2,4,2,4,2,\dots
\end{equation}

Now we will take the difference (not the absolute difference) of the $2$'nd row with the first:

\begin{equation}
2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,\dots
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
1,2,2,4,2,4,2,\dots
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
1,1,3,3,9,9,15,\dots
\end{equation}

Again now we repeat the process of taking the absolute difference between adjacent neighbors:

\begin{equation}
2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,\dots
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
1,2,2,4,2,4,2,\dots
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
1,1,3,3,9,9,15,\dots
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
0,2,0,6,0,6,\dots
\end{equation}

Again now we take the difference between this foremost row and the one preceding it:

\begin{equation}
2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,\dots
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
1,2,2,4,2,4,2,\dots
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
1,1,3,3,9,9,15,\dots
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
0,2,0,6,0,6,\dots
\end{equation}

Alternating between these two procedures indefinitely on sees a pattern emerge:

\begin{equation}
2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,\dots
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
1,2,2,4,2,4,2,\dots
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
1,\textbf{1},3,3,9,9,15,\dots
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
0,\textbf{2},0,6,0,6,\dots
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\textbf{1},\textbf{-1},3,-3,9,3,\dots
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\textbf{2},\textbf{4},6,12,6,\dots
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\textbf{-1},\textbf{-5},-3,-15,3,\dots
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\textbf{4},\textbf{2},12,18,\dots
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\textbf{-5},\textbf{-7},-15,-33,\dots
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\textbf{2},\textbf{8},18,\dots
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\textbf{-7},\textbf{-15},10,\dots
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\textbf{8},\textbf{25},\dots
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\textbf{-15},-40,\dots
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\textbf{25},\dots
\end{equation}

We note that in the number $1$ in bold in rowrepeats again in row. Similarly we see the bold $2$ repeats in another row. And so on for every bold number. Hence, as a pattern has emerged the sequence contains structure.

[image]

### Algebraic Representation

The above manipulations can also be represented algebraically using a nilpotent matrix. Consider the following example of primes, again. But first some definitions:

Let $x = 1 - \epsilon $
 where 1 represents the identity matrix and epsilon is a nilpotent matrix such that $\epsilon^2 = 0$. We define $y$ satisfying the properties:
$ xy =1$ and $x^\lambda + y^\lambda = 2$ for any $\lambda$ being an integer.

\begin{equation}
K = s x^2 + s^2 x^3 + s^3 x^5 + \dots
\end{equation}

Multiplying $s$ both sides we get:

\begin{equation}
Ks = 0+ s^2 x^2 + s^3 x^3 + s^4 x^5 + \dots
\end{equation}

Subtracting the equations one gets:

\begin{equation}
K(s-1) = -s x^2 + s^2 x^2(1-x) + s^3 x^3(1-x^2 ) + \dots
\end{equation}

Note in the above procedure this is quite similar to taking absolute difference between the primes. 
Now, using $x^\lambda + y^\lambda = 2$:

\begin{equation}
K(s-1) = -s x^2 + s^2 x^2(y-1) + s^3 x^3(y^2-1 ) + \dots
\end{equation}

Defining $K_1$ as a sequence with only positive coefficients: $K_1 = s x^2 + s^2 x^2 + s^3 x^3 + \dots$ and using $ xy =1$. Hence,

\begin{equation}
K(s-1) + K_1 = s^2 x + s^3 x + \dots
\end{equation}

Note the above step is similar to subtraction between rows!

Hence, we can represent all the manipulations algebraically!

=

### Questions

What are some non random sequences row math does not make a pattern emerge (I've tried it for Fibonacci, geometric, etc)? And a pattern emerges everytime (for some reason). Why does a pattern emerge to begin with?

Comment: The words "pattern" and "structure" have been used loosely with intuitive meaning ...

Comment: It seems that you have a notion of "random".

Comment: Perhaps the words non-algorithmically generated sequence would have been better?

Comment: So, one wouldn't know how to generate the primes (that we all know how to generate)?

Comment: One can generate the primes algorithmically (using a sieve) and hence row math makes a pattern emerge ... I dont seem to understand your comment

Comment: @TheGreatDuck I think I've edited my question to be even clearer now (about the randomness ) ... by randomness I'm referring to non-deterministic

Comment: By randomly flipping a coin, I can produce a sequence $00000\ldots$.  There is a very well known theory of random infinite sequences, known as the theory of Martin-Lof randomness. But that theory does not try to ask whether a sequence was produced by a non-deterministic Turing machine, because *every* sequence can be produced by a nondeterministic Turing machine.

Comment: @CarlMummert let's take the example of a flipping coin ... The odds of it producing $0,0,0\dots$ forever is abysmally(/infinitesimally) low  for an infinite sequence. But I think intuitively I feel like my algorithm takes a sequence which has some "sense" behind it and creates a pattern/fractal out of it

Comment: Of course, I'm not a computer scientist by training so I can't describe my intuition in correct terminology :(

Comment: @More Anonymous:  yes, the odds are zero. But it *could* be generated by a nondeterministic Turing machine, following one of the legal execution paths.   Your example is interesting, though.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Only the evolution of the wave function (in quantum mechanics) is deterministic it's collapse is probabilistic ... If one does the double slit experiment and only waits for the first electron to hit the screen and redoes the same experiment one can redo the same experiment and with exact intial conditions and the electron will hit (probably) somewhere else ...

Comment: @CarlMummert Thank you! Would it be better if I said let $U$ be the set of all possible sequences and $L $ be the set of all possible sequences that can be created by a finite memory computer producing an infinite sequence. Then this algorithm helps us distinguish between $L $ and $U-L $?

Comment: @TheGreatDuck I think your views on the universe warrant a question on physics atackezxhange: "is randomness possible" or something that? The mainstream view is then cat is both dead and alive

Comment: Also reason for downvote?

Comment: Worth noting, a remarkable number of algorithms in the field of cryptography depend on it being difficult to distinguish a Pseudo Random Number Genrator (PRNG), aka a deterministic computer program generating an infinite stream of output, and a Random Number Generator (RNG), such as resistor noise or radioactive decay.  If you find an algorithm to do what you want, you will become *instantly* famous in the cryptography community.

Answer (score 4):

It looks to me like your method always produces this pattern.

Here is a list of random integers between 1 and 10, and the result of your procedure:

$$
\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
 10 & 7 & 8 & 5 & 10 & 8 & 5 & 3 & 3 & 1 \\
 3 & 1 & 3 & 5 & 2 & 3 & 2 & 0 & 2 & \text{} \\
 7 & 6 & 5 & 0 & 8 & 5 & 3 & 3 & 1 & \text{} \\
 1 & 1 & 5 & 8 & 3 & 2 & 0 & 2 & \text{} & \text{} \\
 6 & 5 & 0 & -8 & 5 & 3 & 3 & 1 & \text{} & \text{} \\
 1 & 5 & 8 & 13 & 2 & 0 & 2 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 5 & 0 & -8 & -21 & 3 & 3 & 1 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 5 & 8 & 13 & 24 & 0 & 2 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 0 & -8 & -21 & -45 & 3 & 1 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 8 & 13 & 24 & 48 & 2 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 -8 & -21 & -45 & -93 & 1 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 13 & 24 & 48 & 94 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 -21 & -45 & -93 & -187 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 24 & 48 & 94 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 -45 & -93 & -187 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{}
   \\
 48 & 94 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{}
   \\
 -93 & -187 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} &
   \text{} \\
 94 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} &
   \text{} \\
 -187 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} &
   \text{} \\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Thus we learn an important lesson on the necessity of testing a classification scheme not just on positive examples but also negative ones.

Comment: that's quite interesting are you sure you didn't pick the pattern first and then reverse engineer the numbers ? Is this true for all "random" numbers ?

Comment: Also while the definition of pattern is vague I feel it is improbable any pattern would pursisit in an infinite sequence .....

Comment: Also there was a comment which said $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,... $ creates a different pattern

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself before insinuating fabrication on my part?

Comment: I did with 2,3,5,7,1,,2,5,8,9 ...

Comment: Also did a random generator program design your sequence by any chance ?

Comment: Also I thought it was a clever proof on your behalf not fabrication ...

Comment: Yes, I had a random number generator ([this one](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomInteger.html) in particular, if you care) generate several random integer sequences and they all showed the same pattern. I just picked one example to post in my answer.

Comment: I see ... it's interesting that none of my handwritten sequences didn't produce any pattern ...

Comment: I don't want to explicitly spell out my thoughts but: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator

Answer (score 4):

> Why does a pattern emerge to begin with?

Regardless of the source of the first row (deterministic vs. non-deterministic, random vs. non-random, etc.), your procedure may naturally produce that pattern  because (1) it produces the pattern just when a row contains non-increasing segments, (2) it always replaces non-increasing segments by other non-increasing segments (thus maintaining the pattern once it appears), whereas (3) it often replaces increasing segments by non-increasing segments.

To see this, consider just the odd-numbered rows, the first row being row #1. If the $i$th element of an odd row equals the $(i+1)$th element of the preceding odd row, then let us say that those two positions exhibit "Pattern A" -- i.e., the pattern you've noticed.

Now if $(a,b,c,\dots)$ is any segment of an odd row, then the next odd row contains, in the same positions, segment $(a-|a-b|,\ b-|b-c|,\ldots)$; so, if $a\ge b$, then $a-|a-b|=b\ge b-|b-c|$, and the non-increasing pair $(a,b)$ is just replaced by another non-increasing pair $(b,\ b-|b-c|)$, thus exhibiting Pattern A in those positions in those two rows *and in all future odd rows*.

Hence, *any segment of non-increasing values* will generate Pattern A, and *this pattern is **permanent**, as the "non-increasingness" persists in all future odd rows*. On the other hand, examples show that the "increasingness" of a segment is often **transient**, so we should not be surprised to see Pattern A arising as some increasing segments get replaced by permanent non-increasing segments. (Evidently, a similar phenomenon occurs also among even-numbered rows.)

**NB**: If a sequence is not strictly increasing, then it is guaranteed to produce Pattern A in *some* positions, so I think there are some interesting unanswered questions concerning the odd rows:

1. What property of a *strictly increasing* sequence guarantees that it will never produce Pattern A (i.e., that it never generates a *non-increasing* segment). The only examples I've found are linearly increasing sequences; i.e., $x_n = an+b,\ \ a>0.$ Are there others?
2. What property of a sequence guarantees that it will never produce Pattern A *in a particular place* (i.e., that a particular increasing adjacent pair $(a,b)$ does not eventually get replaced by a non-increasing pair)?

   For the sequence of primes, here's a picture showing whether the first $80$ (overlapping) pairs in each odd row are increasing $(+)$ or non-increasing $(-)$; i.e., Pattern A occurs at every $(-)$. The index here counts how many odd rows precede it:

[image: +/- picture for the primes sequence]

For the sequence of primes, do *all* pairs -- no matter how far down a row -- eventually become non-increasing (and hence exhibit Pattern A)?

Many very regular sequences have proper sub-regions where Pattern A seems to never appear, e.g., the Fibonacci sequence:

[image: +/- picture for the Fibonacci sequence]

How to prove here that the $(+)$ (increasing) pairs in alternate positions  *never* get converted to $(-)$ (non-increasing) pairs?