# What is this property of randomness called?

Tags: statistics, reference-request, computer-science, random

### Question

Using this definition of a random process is a sequence of random variables whose outcomes do not follow a deterministic pattern, but follow an evolution described by probability distributions.

I have an intuitive notion of a property of a random sequence. That the sequence should remain random after "random" series of operations (depending on the entries of the sequence) of addition and modulus subtraction (modulus). What is this notion/property of randomness called? Does it hold?

### Example

Let the $n$'th term be $a_n$ then $b_n = |a_n - a_{n+1}| - a_{n+1} $

If $a_n$ is a random sequence, so is $b_n$

### Motivation

[Algorithm to tell if an infinite sequence is random or not?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2625467/algorithm-to-tell-if-an-infinite-sequence-is-random-or-not?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 1):

It is not precisely clear what definition of randomness you use when you say a sequence of numbers "is random" or "stays random". But I assume you mean something like the following:

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 2}$ and let $X_1,X_2,... \Omega : \rightarrow \{1,...,n\}$ be independent, discrete random variables and let each $X_i$ be uniformly distributed on the set $\{1,...,n\}$. Then, for each $w \in \Omega$, the sequence $$ s(\omega):= (X_1(w),X_2(\omega),...) $$ could be called a  *random* sequence. This is the most straightforward definition of randomness.

If you would now (say) use addition of components to form a new sequence
$$ s_{+}(\omega) := (X_1(\omega)+X_2(\omega), X_2(\omega)+X_3(\omega),...)  ,$$
then all entries of $s_{+}$ are still identically distributed, but they have lost their independence. To see this, imagine that $X_i(\omega)+X_{i+1}(\omega)$ is very high. This would imply an increased probability that $X_{i+1}(\omega)$ is very high, which in turn would imply an increased probability that the next entry $X_{i+1}(\omega)+X_{i+2}(\omega)$ is very high as well.

Since the sequence $s_+$ has no independent entries anymore, it is in this sense less random then the sequence $s$. As a rule of thumb: the more operations (addition, subtraction, division of components,...) you apply to $s$, the more dependent the entries of the resulting sequence will get and the more patterns will emerge, which will make the sequence less random in an intuitive sense.

The point is, if you accept the definition from above about what it means for a sequence $s$ of natural numbers to be random, then it is impossibe for the sequence $s_+$ to be random as well according to the same definition of randomness. The same holds for similar sequences $s_-,s_*,...$. As soon as the entries of the sequence loose their independence, patterns can and will emerge in the long run.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I seem to have given a terrible example in hindsight. What if the operation used depends on $X_i(\omega)$ and $X_{i+1}(\omega)$ as in the motivation? Does your argument still hold?

Comment: With this "definition", it seems that *every* sequence is declared random.

Comment: Reason for downvote? I've edited it.. Hopefully it's more reasonable now

Comment: @Did. No, of course not every sequence is random according to my definition. You seem to be confused about the role of independence of the components of the sequence, which is crucial for the definition.

Comment: Unfortunately, the independence condition disappears when one passes at the level of some given $\omega$. Example: $(X_n)$ i.i.d. Bernoulli, then the sequence $(1,1,1,\ldots)$ **does correspond to some given $\omega$**... thus you would declare it "random"?

Comment: Yes it is still random. A counterexample: lets say you play the lottery and the number that comes up is 145823. Then you would agree that the number is random. But if the number that comes up is 123456 (or 111111 for that matter), then your claim would be that the lottery did not produce a random sequence?

Comment: I do not know what you are asking exactly, and anyway I have to ask: do you think that a framework leading to declare that (1,1,1,1,....) is random, can be of any relevance? Not to mention that nobody uses it... (Unrelated: Please @.)

Comment: Are you telling me that people are not calling i.i.d. sequences random sequences on occasion? You seem to confuse "random" will something more like "well-mixed". I am giving a definition for a process which produces random sequences; you seem to be concerned with a definition of a measure of "well-mixedness" of a particular instantiation of a single sequence. It is not clear at all, however, how the fact that a sequence is well-mixed implies that it is the product of a random process, and therefore random in this (rigorous) sense.

Comment: (Again no @.) You might wish to spend less time decreeing that people are confused about this and that or do not know this and that (which, in the present case, is simply laughable) and more explaining the at present quite imprecise considerations presented in your post. It happens that you defined the fact for a single sequence of numbers to be "random" as being the sequence of values of some i.i.d. random variables at some fixed $\omega$. This "definition" is absurd, for the reason I mentioned,  so now, you may either try to correct it, or continue these denegations. Your choice.